# Using custom font in WKWebView without setting baseURL to bundleURL

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to use local custom font **without setting WKWebView baseURL to bundleURL**. Is there a way to use something like an absolute URL to the file in the bundle?

I tried this (getting an URL of the file, using it in a string and appending local CSS with that string):

```
let fontURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MaterialIcons-Regular", withExtension: "ttf")!

let fontFace = """
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    src: url(\(fontURL.absoluteString)) format('truetype');
}
"""
```

(And other ways to get the file URL) And it didn't work.

If I use an URL like `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/material-design-icons/master/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf` instead of the fontURL.absoluteString in my code, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use fonts which are installed by your app (using section "Fonts provided by application") in info plist file. Then you can use following way `font-family: 'FrutigerLTPro-Roman'` in CSS

Comment: This worked with UIWebView but apparently doesn't work with WKWebView since it runs outside of the main app's process.